# Why did Google develop Puppeteer if Protractor was already there?

Tags: angular, selenium, automation, protractor, puppeteer

Does anybody know why Google decided to develop Puppeteer when there was Protractor already? (specially for Angular)

Comment: why did google develop chrome, if there were EDGE and IE out there?

Answer (score 7):

There are a few fundamental differences between [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#puppeteer) and [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor#protractor---)

- Protractor is an external web application testing tool while Puppeteer is node module of the Chromium engine.
- Chromium being a browser, Puppeteer is pretty faster compared to Protractor.
- Protractor can be used to automate the different browsers like [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge), [opera](/questions/tagged/opera), [brave](/questions/tagged/brave), etc. But using Puppeteer you'd be able to automate the chromium engine only. As of today only *Chrome* and *Microsoft Edge* browser are using the Chromium engine.
- Puppeteer can test APIs using request/responses but with Protractor it is a bit complicated.
- You can check the amount of time taken to load the page with Puppeteer but Protractor does not have feature for it.
- Puppeteer can be used to check how much of CSS/JS files are used for loading a page which won't be possible using Protractor.
- You can test the application without loading the images in Puppeteer but that isn't possible through Protractor.
- You can use all the [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) of chrome in Puppeteer but Protractor does not support it.
- You can execute the test in different devices using the emulators in the puppeteer but emulating a device in Protractor is complicated.
- You can save the screenshots in image and pdf format in puppeteer where as Protractor provide a feature to save a screenshot in image format only.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, i believe he is asking more about the political decision from Google to start and develop a project like Puppeteer to do automation when there was already Protractor (wrapper to Selenium), do you know? i am also interested

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for the answer, It was really good and clear but I'm asking about the Google Decision, what Fernando mentioned in the previous message; I wanted to know why the support focus is today on Puppeteer instead of protractor.

Comment: @EstebanCiccarelli I am guessing decision was made because of all the points DebanjanB mentioned above.